# coldfusion/sql ASC order with blanks at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion, sql-order-by

I've got a query where I change the sort order dynamically based on user input. I'd like to have the blank matches show up at the end. Is this possible with a way that's relatively painless that won't need to create a separate query for every possibility of sort request?

Comment: Could you add a sample data and what is the desire output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another item to your `ORDER BY` list. If your column name is `user_input` for example you'd have.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN user_input = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, user_input
```

This would put everything with a value first and then sort alphabetically after that and put all the blank values at the end.

Note: If you have `NULL` values rather than blanks you'll have to account for those too using `isNull()`

Comment: I had to use the later `ORDER BY CASE WHEN user_input IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, user_input`. Worked like a charm - Thanks